# Keyboard shortcut to unmark all emails in Yahoo! Mail

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, yahoo-mail

We can mark all emails using keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> in [Yahoo! Mail](http://mail.yahoo.com/). Are there any keyboard shortcut to unmark all emails?

**Edit**

> [image]    =>    [image]

**Note:** Keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> is not listed [here](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/yahoomail/basics/basics-65.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try pressing <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> or <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>.

Comment: It will only unmark all emails if all emails are marked using Ctrl+A. If some emails are marked it cannot able to unmark all emails.

Comment: In that case <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> followed by <kbd>Up Arrow</kbd> or <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of the keyboard shortcuts available in Yahoo! Mail.

http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/yahoomail/basics/basics-65.html

By unmark do you mean "Mark as Unread"?

Comment: See I edited my post..

Answer (score -1):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> again and that will deselect all messages.

Comment: Not working in Yahoo Mail Neo...